# httpd does not parse php when using with root alias

Tags: apache, zabbix

I have installed zabbix gui on centos 7 by default installation. Then it has come with zabbix.conf file and all config is done.

```
Alias /zabbix /usr/share/zabbix
```

when I write the address http://serverip/zabbix I can access the zabbix web. But When I change the Alias like this

```
Alias / /usr/share/zabbix
```

I see the php files list in zabbix directory. Finally I had to change the Alias definition to DocumentRoot definition then it worked. What should be done to make Alias definition work with php?

Comment: any .htaccess in `zabbix`, what's inside?

Comment: @Ben None, I have have checked it first, but there is not.

Comment: The `Alias` directive allows documents to be stored in the local filesystem other than under the DocumentRoot. Why did you set `Alias / /usr/share/zabbix`? `DocumentRoot /usr/share/zabbix` is proper settings